# Using C# or WMI to get USB drive capacity when no partitions defined

Tags: c#, wmi, disk, diskspace

I have written a C# program which populates one or more bootable USB pen drives from a standard build source. The user chooses the target drives by their drive letters.

I check in the code that there is enough capacity on each target USB device before starting, but I can't work out how to do this if there are no partitions defined on the device.

I can see how to use WMI to find the physical disk based on the drive letter, but this relies on the "Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition" relationship, which won't work when there are no partitions.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you locate the USB device without a drive letter? Unpartitioned devices aren't supposed to be mapped to a drive letter.

Comment: @Tomer Here is an example on my Windows 7 machine of a SanDisk USB device with no partitions:
<pre>
DISKPART> list vol
 
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 5     F                       Removable       0 B  Unusable</pre>

Comment: Did you try to query `Win32_DiskDrive`? It has a size property.

Comment: Sorry, struggling to make it readable, but I'm sure you can work it out :)

Comment: @Tomer, yes, the problem is how do I get from the drive letter to the correct instance of Win32_DiskDrive, as it doesn't mention a drive letter?

Comment: My point is, there is no drive letter, because drive letters are only assigned to partitions.

Comment: As shown in the DiskPart output above, Volume 5 has a drive letter of F but no partitions. You can recreate this by entering the diskpart commands SEL VOL X then CLEAN. Windows will still show the letter.

Comment: @intDattashame Can't you just query `Win32_DiskDrive` for a USB InterfaceType, or will there be a bunch of USB drives plugged in at once? (EG - `WMIC PATH Win32_DiskDrive WHERE (InterfaceType="USB") GET Size`)